# Understanding for loop semantics when iterating through a vector containing mutable references

Tags: reference, rust

I am trying to understand why the following code fails:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 10;
    let mut b = 20;
    let mut c = 30;
    let p = vec![&mut a, &mut b, &mut c]; // works with [&a, &b, &c]

    for &x in &p { // works with 'x' instead of of '&x'
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |     for &x in &p {
  |         ^-
  |         ||
  |         |hint: to prevent move, use `ref x` or `ref mut x`
  |         cannot move out of borrowed content
```

As I understand, the 'borrowed content' is the mutable references to variables `a`, `b`, `c` by the `vec!`, but what exactly is getting "moved" here? I presume the move is happening in the beginning of the `for` loop.

I think there are two mutable references (one by `vec`) being held, but I guess I am not able to deconstruct `&x` properly for my understanding and I know the answer lies there. I am able to understand why it works if I put `ref x` in there as suggested by the compiler or use `&&mut x`, but I'm not  understanding the aforementioned case. (i.e `&x`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little tricky because bindings in Rust can be a little tricky, but first let's see what we're dealing with and start with some code that does compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 10;
    let mut b = 20;
    let mut c = 30;
    let p = vec![&mut a, &mut b, &mut c];

    for x in &p {              // note the lack of &x
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

This prints out the numbers 10, 20, 30 like you'd expect, but why? Lets change the code to get an error that will tell us what `x` is:

```
for x in &p {              // note the lack of &x
    x + ();
}
```

You then see `error[E0369]: binary operation + cannot be applied to type &&mut {integer}`

What you get out of iterating over `&p` is a reference to a mutable reference to an integer. Specifically you get a reference to a vector-owned mutable reference to an integer. The loop cannot obtain a copy of that mutable reference because having two outstanding mutable references is a no-no. If you're not moving that mutable reference out of the vector, the for loop will have to settle for having an immutable borrow of that mutable reference. Here's some code that demonstrates what I'm saying:

```
let borrow = &p[0];
assert_eq!(borrow, &&mut 10);

// Try to get our own `&mut 10` out of `borrow`    
let gimme = *borrow; // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
```

---

Now let's talk about what doing `for &x in &p` does. Here are two equivalent loops that give you the same `x` and also give you the same error.

```
for &x in &p {           
}

for temp in &p {
    let x = *temp;
}
```

This is because `for &x in ...` is a destructuring binding. You're asserting "`&x` matches the structure of an item from iterating over `&p`. I want `x` to be the part of that match without the first `&`."

It's similar to this:

```
let borrow = &p[0];
assert_eq!(borrow, &&mut 10);

// Try to get our own `&mut 10` out of `borrow`    
let gimme = *borrow; // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content    
let &gimme_gimme = borrow;  // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
```

In this case, `&x` matches `&&mut {integer}` where `&` matches the first `&` and `x` then becomes bound to what's left (`&mut {integer}`).

I've already explained why you cant have your own copy of that `&mut {integer}`.