# tuple destructuring in for loops?

Tags: for-loop, rust, reference, tuples

This compiles and outputs: `i32`

```rust
fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

pub fn main() {
    let regions = [
        // From 0xe0000 to 0xfffff
        (0xe0000, 0xfffff),
    ];

    for (start, end) in &regions {
        print_type_of(start);
    }
}
```

This fails

```rust
fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

pub fn main() {
    let regions = [
        // From 0xe0000 to 0xfffff
        (0xe0000, 0xfffff),
    ];

    // NEW
    for &(start, end) in &regions {
        print_type_of(start);
    }
}
```

with

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> test.rs:12:27
   |
12 |             print_type_of(start);
   |                           ^^^^^
   |                           |
   |                           expected reference, found integer
   |                           help: consider borrowing here: `&start`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&_`
                   found type `{integer}`
```

Why does `for &(start, end) in &regions`
capture `start` and `end` as an int value
but `for (start, end) in &regions` as a reference?

Comment: read my question again

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160436/understanding-for-loop-semantics-when-iterating-through-a-vector-containing-muta

Comment: @Stargateur ahh not quite it's similiar but different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

pub fn main() {
    let &a = &32_i32;
    let b = 32_i32;
    print_type_of(&a);
    print_type_of(&b);
}
```

the output will be:

```
i32
i32
```

In the example, `&a = &32_i32` is equivalent to `b = 32_i32`. The `&` in the left value will become the dereference of the right value, this is part of the [Destructuring Pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html). Your code is equivalent to:

```
fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

pub fn main() {
    let regions = [
        // From 0xe0000 to 0xfffff
        (0xe0000, 0xfffff)
    ];

    // NEW
    for (start, end) in regions {
        print_type_of(start);
    }
}
```

So `(start, end) = (0xe0000, 0xfffff)`, `start`'s type is `i32`.

Comment: Also helpful: "Reference patterns dereference the pointers that are being matched and, thus, borrow them." https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns